# Export OpenAPI definition using c# SDK Azure.ResourceManager.ApiManagement

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, openapi, azure-resource-manager

With PowerShell I can export OpenAPI definitions from APIM like that:

```
Export-AzApiManagementApi 
    -Context $apimContext 
    -ApiId $apiId 
    -SpecificationFormat OpenApiJson 
| Out-File -FilePath ($openApiExportDirectory + "$apiId.json")
```

How do I do that with [Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/azure-sdk-for-dotnet)?

I can get `ApiCollection` from:

```
  ArmClient >
    GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync() >
        GetResourceGroupAsync() >
            GetApiManagementServiceAsync() >
                GetApis()
```

I can iterate through every `ApiResource` in the `ApiCollection` but they do not include OpenAPI specs. Probably it needs to be generated, and there should be a method for that. I cannot find such a method. I looked in `ApiManagementServiceResource` and I cannot find anything that would do that.

Any ideas on how to get the OpenAPI definition for each API using SDK? (Not REST or CLI or PS)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to get the OpenAPI definition for each API using SDK?  (Not REST or CLI or PS)

You can use Python SDK to export open API definitions using [azure-mgmt-apimanagement · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-apimanagement/)  package.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.apimanagement import ApiManagementClient


client = ApiManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id="Your-subscription-id",
    )

response = client.api_export.get(
        resource_group_name="Your-resource-grp",
        service_name="Your-service name",
        api_id="Your-api-id",
        format="openapi+json-link",
        export="true",
    )
print(response)
```

**Output:**

```
{'`additional_properties': {'name': 'xxxx', 'type': 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis', 'properties': {'format': 'openapi+json-link', 'value': {'link': 'https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/api-export/xxx.json?sv=2017-04-17&sr=b&sig=Ae%2FQudIEzLvT5h6vL%2B2enacYS9YyWbxxxx&se=2023-04-29T04:53:08Z&sp=r'}}}, 'id': '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/xxxx/apis/xxx', 'export_result_format': None, 'value': None}`
```

[image]

You can copy the value(link) in the output result and paste it into the browser you will get the JSON format.

**Browser:**

[image]

Comment: That's the thing, I know how to do it with Cli, PS, REST, and now Py, but I would like to make it work with Azure SDK for .Net.